# I want to write LINQ to SQL query dynamically

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

Look, for example I have a model with 2 tables and each one has one field

```
tbl1 > fld1
tbl2 > fld2
```

Now I want to have a void or something like it that gets tables name and field names and returns LINQ-to- SQL queries,

```
protected void InsertQuery(tablename, fieldnames)
{
  // do some insert query that "i don't know about table name and fields"
}
```

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Comment: A void does not return. Please be more specific about what exactly you expect `InsertQuery()` to generate.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will not have any benefit using Linq-2-sql in this case (compared to ordinary creation of SQL statements and use ADO.NET ).

Beause:

- you want a void - there is not return type.
- there is no use of strong
  types

So you only get overhead from Linq-2-sql, not benefit. So I would not do it.